# How to resolve this issue "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)."?

Tags: botframework

I am working on bot framework technology, in one of my project I implemented the concept of “Authorize access to web applications using OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory” to my current bot.

It’s working in locally fine using bot framework channel emulator, after that I have published my bot into azure and added a skype channel to it.

Next I started to chat with my bot, when I click on this URL https://bankivrcallingbot.azurewebsites.net/api/29:1LFUEWsOCTRAjSGXvSbsESUgPgwwns4PUh7l8vgKP_znay9FRGiLd0Cm6xO5Undeo/login it shows Server Error in '/' Application and A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

See the below screen shot for complete understand about my error.
[image]

Please tell how to resolve this error as soon as possible.

-Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

The : character is not allowed in the path of the URL

Comment: but I want to allow the : character in my URL(https://bankivrcallingbot.azurewebsites.net/api/29:1LFUEWsOCTRAjSGXvSbsESUgPgwwns4PUh7l8vgKP_znay9FRGiLd0Cm6xO5Undeo/login) Please tell me how to solve it, I tried : replace with 3A but it's not working.

Comment: This is part of the RFC specification for URLs:  http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html

Comment: When I was encoded my url also it shows same  above exception, this is my  url  var url = $"https://userpresencebot.azurewebsites.net/api/"+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(activity.From.Id)+"/login";  this Url used in sign-in card for bot development.

Comment: I know : is reserved character but I want to allow the colon character in my url because skype channel contains the Id like this below "29:1_12CsCTqilHlQTG9KI8YmvCKd-zwzekm2IDKR7xN8EVE3gjtfNQYp1aOzuC9Rs_t", by using this id I can get bot state and set some values in it.

Comment: Please tell me as soon as possible, because this is an urgent requirement of client.

Comment: Why not substitute another character? (i.e. "-" for ":")

Comment: I replaced : with - it's working fine but when I am trying to get the bot state at that time I faced the problem please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483415/unable-to-deserialize-the-response-getuserdataasync

Answer (score 0):

My issue in Azure Data Factory was also about the : character.

I resolved the problem **by substituting : with %3A**

as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP).

For example, I substituted

```
date1=2020-01-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

with

```
date1=2020-01-25T00%3A00%3A00.000Z
```