# Unable to deserialize the response - GetUserDataAsync

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I am working bot technology, in one of my project I used bot state concept to get the bot data and set new data here I used state client object like this below

```
 //var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9000/"));
   var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("https://skype.botframework.com"));
```

This is code I wrote in LoginController.cs

```
                if (stateClient != null)
                {
                    var getData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, activity.From.Id);// 29:1_12CsCTqilHlQTG9KI8YmvCKd - zwzekm2IDKR7xN8EVE3gjtfNQYp1aOzuC9Rs_t
                    //var getData = await client.B.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid);
                    getData.Data = ar.Serialize();
                    var foo = await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, activity.From.Id, getData);
                    //var foo = await client.Bots.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid, getData);
                }
```

The above code will work in bot emulator successfully without exception. but when I added bot to skype then started to chat at that time I am getting exception  'Unable to deserialize the response' after executed this line

```
var getData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, activity.From.Id);
```

Please tell me how resolve it.

Comment: What is the size of the data you are trying to serialize?   The Bot State Service is only intended to store small amounts of state data (< 64k total) not large objects.  If you want to store larger items you can put a hash into the UserData and then do a lookup in either a separate storage service (i.e Azure Storage) or on a local cache.   (Please confirm if this was the issue.  Thanks)

Comment: I am getting the above exception here var getData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, activity.From.Id); and I am trying to serialize the 10K data.

Comment: Have you tried using the helper to create your state client: StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();

Comment: I know by using activity reference we can create state client object but in my scenario I want to create the state client object in my login controller not in message controller. when I click on this var url = $"userpresencebot.azurewebsites.net/api/…; url it will go to login controller.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use https://state.botframework.com as the endpoint for the StateClient rather than skype.botframework.com.

Comment: i tried with above url already,  then also I got the same above exception

Comment: Tell me the above url is applicable to all channels like group me and slack channels etc.....

Comment: I tried with above url at that time I got " Bad Request Exception" I think the service url of the skype is like https://skype.botframework.com